# NoSuchMethodError: The method 'markNeedsBuild' was called on null

Tags: flutter

A `NoSuchMethodError: The method 'markNeedsBuild' was called on null.` error appears in error logs. I've never seen this error in debugging and users are not reporting any issues. Why does this error occur and is there anything I can do to prevent it from occuring?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`'NoSuchMethodError: The method 'markNeedsBuild' was called on null.'` is caused by calling `setState()` after a widget is disposed.

Most commonly, this happens when an async network operation completes and tries to update the widget but the widget has already been disposed.

Example:

```dart
await networkProvider.getData().then((value) {
    // Update data.
    setState(() {
        data = value;
    });
});
```

To avoid updating widgets after they are disposed, check to ensure the widget still exists before calling `setState`. Here's an updated version of the example above that prevents `NoSuchMethodError`.

```dart
await networkProvider.getData().then((value) {
    // Check if widget still exists.
    if (mounted) {
        // Update data.
        setState(() {
            data = value;
        });
    }
});
```